# Django can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, django

I have this logic in my views and models, in my views i get the data of what the user inputted, and in my models, i have an automatic computation of `discount_price_formula`, and `other_discount_price_formula` why i am having this error? `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`. how do i solve this problem?

this is my views.py

```
otherdiscountpercentage = request.POST.get("otherdiscountpercentage")
S_price = request.POST.get("price")
otherdiscountprice = request.POST.get("otherdiscountprice")
discountpercentage = request.POST.get("discountpercentage")
discountprice = request.POST.get("discountprice")

insert_data = Product(
    price=S_price,
    discount_percentage=discountpercentage,
    discount_price=discountprice,
    Other_discount_percentage=otherdiscountpercentage,
    Other_discount_price=otherdiscountprice,
)
```

this is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Unit Price")

    discount_percentage = models.FloatField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    discount_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    Other_discount_percentage = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    Other_discount_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    discount_price_formula = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    other_discount_price_formula = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.discount_price_formula = self.price - (self.price * self.discount_percentage)

        self.other_discount_price_formula = (self.price - (self.price * self.discount_percentage)) - ((self.price - (self.price * self.discount_percentage)) * self.Other_discount_percentage)
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.product}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

this is my traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Desktop\onlinestoreapp\customAdmin\views.py" in InsertProduct
  293.     insert_data.save()

File "C:\Users\Desktop\onlinestoreapp\customAdmin\models.py" in save
  209.         self.discount_price_formula = self.price - (self.price * self.discount_percentage)

Exception Type: TypeError at /InsertProduct/
Exception Value: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values coming from a request are by default `str` type but Django does the conversion directly. Since you're overwriting the `save` method, you need to convert them to int, like this:

```
otherdiscountpercentage = request.POST.get("otherdiscountpercentage")
if otherdiscountpercentage:
    otherdiscountpercentage = float(otherdiscountpercentage)
```

Beware that using `request.POST.get('param_name')` means the param is optional. So you should put some condition or give a default float value before any calculation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
otherdiscountpercentage = request.POST.get("otherdiscountpercentage")
S_price = request.POST.get("price")
otherdiscountprice = request.POST.get("otherdiscountprice")
discountpercentage = request.POST.get("discountpercentage")
discountprice = request.POST.get("discountprice")

insert_data = Product(
    price=float(S_price),
    discount_percentage=float(discountpercentage),
    discount_price=float(discountprice),
    Other_discount_percentage=float(otherdiscountpercentage),
    Other_discount_price=float(otherdiscountprice),
)
```